# Checkers board structure

Tags: python

I am implementing a  checkers game board with python.  Here is how I generate the board structure as an [8][8] array:

```
 _matrix = []
 for i in xrange(8):
     _matrix.append( [' '] * 8 )


 for row in xrange(0, 8):
        for col in xrange(0, 8):
            if _darkQuad(row, col) == True:
                _matrix[row][col] = '#'
            else:
                _matrix[row][col] = '-'

def _darkQuad(row, col):
    return ((row%2) == (col%2))

def _printDebugBoard():
    for row in xrange(0, 8):
        for col in xrange(0, 8):
            print _matrix[row][col]
        print ''
```

This should do my board like:

> ```
>  # - # - # - # -
>  - # - # - # - #
>  ...
> ```

But the result is:

```
- - - - - - - - 
# # # # # # # # 
- - - - - - - - 
# # # # # # # # 
- - - - - - - - 
# # # # # # # # 
- - - - - - - - 
# # # # # # # #
```

What's wrong?

---

**UPD**:
Hm, I didn't think this will be important. I made my code easier but here is the exact code I use:

```
class gameSquare(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.validSquare = False
        self.symbol = ''

    def printSymbol(self):
        print self.symbol,
-------
def _validateSquares(self):
    for row in xrange(0, 8):
        for col in xrange(0, 8):
            if self._darkQuad(row, col) == True:
                self._matrix[row][col].validSquare = False
                self._matrix[row][col].symbol = '#'
            else:
                self._matrix[row][col].validSquare = True
                self._matrix[row][col].symbol = '-'

--------
for i in xrange(8):
    self._matrix.append( [gameSquare()] * 8 )

-------
def _printDebugBoard(self):
    print ''
    for row in xrange(0, 8):
        for col in xrange(0, 8):
            self._matrix[row][col].printSymbol()
        print ''
```

Comment: Isn't the `xrange` function deprecated in py 2.6

Comment: @Jweede, I thought that it's faster than range cause it uses iterators. But it's never mind.

Comment: @Jweede, No, `xrange` will remain for the whole 2.x branch of Python and will be autoconverted to `range` by `2to3`.

Comment: Don't know python, but doesn't the range 0-8 have 9 members?

Comment: @MJB: `range(0,8)` is treated like `for(i=0;i<8;i++)`

Comment: @MJB, most ranges in Python are closed-open.

Comment: As an aside, your code doesn't look very "Pythonic".  

In particular, you needn't compare against True so you can just do:

if _darkQuad(row, col) == True:

Camelcase is generally discouraged as well, as (I think) are the extra braces around return: ((row%2) == (col%2))

PEP 8, the Python style guide is a good reference: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

And an article about idiomatic python: http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html

Comment: @Jweede and Mike G - thanks.  I read these to learn sometimes...

Comment: @Dana, yeah, I'm c++ programmer

Comment: You will violate people's expectations if your class's name does not start with a capital letter.

Comment: Dana means *"so you can just do: `if _darkQuad(row, col):`"*

Comment: As an addition to the other answers given, you can also represent your board as a simple array instead of a two dimensional array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update for newly posted code**

The problem is with the line:

```
self._matrix.append( [gameSquare()] * 8 )
```

This will create 8 references on each line to the *same* object. When you change one of them, it will actually change the whole row. To fix it:

```
self._matrix.append( [gameSquare() for _ in xrange(8)] )
```

**End update**

---

Your code works for me. Only thing that needs fixing is:

```
print _matrix[row][col],
```

instead of:

```
print _matrix[row][col]
```

To avoid printing every character on a different line.

I also had to reorder the functions to get the code to run (put `_darkQuad` at the top).

Comment: Yeah, I use class and made code simplier. Please, look updates.

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to reproduce this problem. Modifying the code you posted so that it will run:

```
# Moved this function up here so it can be called.
def _darkQuad(row, col): 
    return row % 2 == col % 2

def _printDebugBoard():
    for row in xrange(8):
        for col in xrange(8):
            print _matrix[row][col],
            # Added the comma here ^ so that I don't get unwanted newlines
        print ''

_matrix = []
for i in xrange(8):
    _matrix.append([' '] * 8)


for row in xrange(8):
    for col in xrange(8):
        if _darkQuad(row, col): 
            _matrix[row][col] = '#'
        else:
            _matrix[row][col] = '-'

_printDebugBoard() # called the _printDebugBoard function
```

gives me:

```
# - # - # - # - 
- # - # - # - # 
# - # - # - # - 
- # - # - # - # 
# - # - # - # - 
- # - # - # - # 
# - # - # - # - 
- # - # - # - #
```

(I also made two changes that didn't affect the result but that reflect better usage. I changed `if _darkQuad(row, col) == True:` to `if _darkQuad(row, col):`, which is how you do if statements and I changed `xrange(0, 8)` to `xrange(8)`, which is the typical usage.)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is:

```
print _matrix[row][col],
```

The comma tells the interpreter to skip the carriage return after the print statement.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for something like this:

```
matrix = ['#-' * 4, '-#' * 4] * 4
```

It keeps the math to a minimum.